# Need some pointers on adapting a php/mysql pagination script for use with odbc .mdb access database

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Im working on a little web based application using php/html and an odbc database. Im trying to figure out how to implement pagination into the application im making, but the only examples I could find were made with mysql and not odbc. I've tried for hours to adapt them, but have come up empty handed so far.

I've replaced every instance of mysql from the script with odbc and dreamweaver is picking them up as valid functions (color highlighting) but the script is producing nothing.

The script I was working off of is located here:
http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=289

I appreciate any help, even if its just a link... Been kicking myself in the head over this for too long.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this tutorial useful.

http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-access/php-access-odbc-and-paging-pagination/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried it out and all its printing out is the table headers and then "Total Record : Page : 1" but no data. Given the query I was expecting 4 rows. I'll keep working at it though.

Maybe it has something to do with "<?=$objResult["name"];?>" that part of the script. I tried changing to <?php=$objResult['..." but im getting syntax error that way.